# Skipping acquire of configured file

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I tried to update my raspberry pi 4 and I got this result.

> $ sudo apt update

```
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease                                                 
Hit:3 https://repos.influxdata.com/debian buster InRelease                                                   
Get:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]                                    
Hit:5 https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages [13.0 MB]
Ign:6 https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt buster InRelease
Hit:8 https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt buster Release 
Fetched 13.0 MB in 50s (263 kB/s)                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

> $ lscpu

```
Architecture:        armv7l
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           ARM
Model:               3
Model name:          Cortex-A72
Stepping:            r0p3
CPU max MHz:         1500.0000
CPU min MHz:         600.0000
BogoMIPS:            108.00
Flags:               half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
```

I am newbie in Linux. I spend my time a lot to figure out this problem and also i can not run node-red and Grafana I have no idea because of it.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this,

Type the following commands:

```
sudo cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
ls -a
```

Go into apt source folder and see what request/hits on the internet it is trying to make and list all the folders so you can identify the name of the folder you need to delete (rethinkdb folder/file)

```
sudo rm <folder/file that is causing the error, in this case, the rethinkdb>

clear 
sudo apt-get update
```

Things should work now. The error was caused because the rethinkdb module you tried to download is not compatible with the architecture of your raspberry pi; so every time you try to update your pi it tries to download that file from the internet and the error happens.